# Python: How to Extract Tables from Multipe Links from Same Page under Specific Headline

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver

I can extract all the tables from a single page (**office 365 and Office 2016 differences**) by supplying the direct link using

```
dfs = pd.read_html(
    "https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-s-the-difference-between-office-365-and-office-2016-ed447ebf-6060-46f9-9e90-a239bd27eb96?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US", header=0)

for df in dfs:
    df
```

How can I extract all the tables under the **Account and Payement** without explicitly having to supply the links for each subpage under **account and payement**?

So basically, it goes on **office 365 and Office 2016 differences** extracts table, then goes to **forgot office username or password** and extracts table, goes to **cancel your subscription** and extracts table. 
If there is no table, it moves on.

Comment: Is your question about how to know if a URL will direct to a page with a table in it?

Comment: @Victor, you can write a method which will have 1 parameter (table web element) and then just print the content of it. Just modify my answer from the previous question.

Comment: @Victor, I see that only the first link has a table. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

None of these headings contain `TABLE` tags so I'm a little confused about what you are referring to there.

If it were me, I would pass in strings as the headings I'm looking to extract links from and then use the XPath locator below to get them.

```
//b[.='Account and payment']//ancestor::div[1]//a[@class='ocpArticleLink']
```

This gets the "Account and payment" title, finds the `DIV` container (it contains all the links for that heading) and then find all the links (excluding the MORE link).

That should get you what you've asked for. You can put this in a function, pass in the heading as a parameter, and have it return the collection of links. Something like the below...

```
def get_links(heading)
    return driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//b[.='" + heading + "']//ancestor::div[1]//a[@class='ocpArticleLink']")
```